# Excel formula to remove intermediate rows

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I've an excel sheet that looks like this:

[image]

I want to remove all the values that isn't a multiple of 0.1., i.e., in the above example, I want to keep only the rows 1.2, 1.3, 1.4 and delete all the intermediate rows. How can I write formula for this?

Thanks.

Comment: A formula in itself cannot delete lines or affect other cells in any way.  You will need vba for that.  You can with excel formulas put a TRUE/FALSE in another column that you then can filter.

Comment: Scott, is it possible to use number filters instead of writing a formula? Sorry, I'm not much familiar with Excel. Excuse me if I mix up with terminologies.

Comment: To follow up with Scott's comment - If you really need Formulas (no VBA), you can accomplish this but will need to use a new worksheet or helper columns. Let us know if VBA is okay or not (you tagged it in the tags, but it's not clear if you want VBA or not).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In at third column, I'd enter the formula:
=ROUND(A1,1)=A1 so it looks like this:

[image]

Then sort on Column C, and delete the FALSE rows.

Comment: Note that if you ever need to parameterize the divisor, `MOD` will be much easier to tweak.

Answer (score 4):

The `MOD` function returns the *remainder* of a division. If that's zero, your value is divisible by the parameter value you gave it:

```
=MOD(A1,0.1)=0
```

Put that in a 3rd column, fill the formula down, and filter out or delete the `FALSE` rows.